# Character Class Regular Expression Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am just wondering in regx why we could not have character class within a character class? for example as below I need to exclude all numbers that starts with 0 , but not 0 it self.

However the square bracket within square bracket is not valid: [[]]

string = re.findall('^[(++)? [1-9][0-9] (++)?]+$',' 01 + 2')

why is that? Is't much easier that we can do such expressions as above?

Many thanks!
Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use *number* ranges within a character class like `[[0-5]]`.
Some regex engines, tools and languages support [POSIX character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) where we can specify `[[:digit:][:punct:]]`.
But that's not the *Python* case.

To exclude all numbers that start with `0` , but not `0` itself use the following approach:

```
s = '01 2 0 33 789 005 4 08 7'
filtered = re.findall(r'\b([1-9]+|0)\b', s)

print(filtered)
```

The output:

```
['2', '0', '33', '789', '4', '7']
```

Comment: Thank You Roman! that's a nifty expression! Just wondering if I want to only include '+' and numbers that does not start with 0 but okay with 0 itself, I think it would be easier to do with class with class, there is no other way I can think of tho.... for example '1 0 ++'

Comment: This would not capture something like `304`. A better pattern might be `r'\b([1-9]\d+|0)\b'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done :

string = re.findall('^[(++)? (1-9d+) (++)?]+$','0 1 +')

it wouldn't capture the 0 as individul number in this case tho....

thanks!
Erik